# MySQL deny login via terminal and phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

I am trying to login to mysql via terminal and phpmyadmin it says cannot access localhost.

Below is the return message when trying to login via the terminal

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES) root@x27:/var/lib/phpmyadmin# mysql --user=root -pass
>   root

I installed the mysqladministrator GUI too.

Comment: have you set a password for root?

Comment: If nothing else works you could simply reset the root password. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Answer (score 0):

You would need to reset the root password - it looks like you supplied an incorrect one.